# I don't understand how I can use define LEFT(phnum + 4)%N at the start of the program when phnum is a local variable inside test

Tags: c

I don't understand how #define LEFT (phnum + 4) % N is allowed as phnum is not even defined.

```
#define N 5 
#define LEFT (phnum + 4) % N 
#define RIGHT (phnum + 1) % N 
  
int state[N]; 
int phil[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
  
sem_t mutex; 
sem_t S[N]; 
  
void test(int phnum) 
{ 
    if (state[phnum] == HUNGRY 
        && state[LEFT] != EATING 
        && state[RIGHT] != EATING) { 
        // state that eating 
        state[phnum] = EATING; 
  
        sleep(2); 
  
        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `#define LEFT (phnum + 4) % N` defines a “macro” named `LEFT` whose replacement list is `(phnum + 4) % N`. The compiler does not need to know anything about the names in the replacement list; it simply remembers it.

When `LEFT` is seen later in the source code, the compiler replaces it with the replacement list, `(phnum + 4) % N`. Thus `state[LEFT] != EATING` becomes `state[(phnum + 4) % N] != EATING`.

After that replacement, the compiler interprets the names according to the declarations it has seen for them.

Conceptually, all of the “preprocessor” operations, such as defining macros, replacing them with their replacement lists, and processing `#if` and other statements marked with `#`, occur before the semantic analysis of the program. It is called “preprocessing” because historically it was done in a separate processing stage before compilation, even with a separate program. In modern compilers, the preprocessor operations may be interleaved with the rest of compilation, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

`#define LEFT (phnum + 4) % N` defines a macro. Macro replacement is performed by the pre-processor *before* the compiler actually compiles your code. In other words `state[LEFT]` gets replaced by `state[(phnum + 4) % N]` before the compiler processes your code.

In case you're using GCC: Passing the `-E` parameter tells GCC to stop after the pre-processing stage so you can inspect the output. Note that the pre-processor also takes care of `#include` lines so you might need to search for the interesting part in the output.